# What is the recommended memory requirement for a Crate host?

Tags: crate

How much memory does a production node need to have to be sure that all features works correctly?

For example, for a dataset between 5GB and 100GB of data.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your use case: how much load you put on the nodes, how fast they need to respond and how big your indices will be. 
We usually use nodes with up to 32 GB of RAM. For your amount of data and given a mediocre use case I guess something like 4 or 8 GB will also do the Job.

Cheers,
Johannes